# Parsing a csv to create a query with no duplicate entries based on one field

Tags: c#, csv, import, duplicates

I think at this point I've just looked at this code so long that the logic is getting fuzzy and I need more eyes on it.

Input is a series of controls that create a few List<> objects. Variables involved are importData, a List which contains "sarray"s, which are string[]s containing a list of field values.   The Lists<> referenced for "validIndeces" and "indecesCantBeDuplicated" contain the indeces of items in importData's sarrays that we actually need, and which ones of those can't have a duplicate in the same field (i.e., no two company ID's the same).

The goal here is to take importData's string[]s, filter out the ones we don't need in the query, execute some instruction to make them compatible with data in a certain table, and then check to ensure that no duplicates exist in a given field.  If a field is indicated in "indecesCantBeDuplicated" and a match is found earlier in the importData in the same index, then it should move on to the next string[] object, otherwise add the line to the query.

Output basically comes out to a series of Insert statements in SQL, but that code is fine.  Here's where I'm stuck.  Why am I not filtering out the duplicates on this?

```
//go through each string array in the import (i.e. each record to import)
foreach (string[] sarray in importData) {
    List<List<string>> QueryList = new List<List<string>>();
    List<string> Queriables = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sarray.Count(); i++) {
        bool addit = true;
        if (validIndeces.Contains(i)) {
        //ensure this is one of the indeces used to import
            if (indecesCantBeDuplicated.Contains(i)) {
                // if THIS index can't have duplicate values
                foreach (string[] s2 in importData) {
                    //check each record in the import
                    foreach(string s in s2) {
                        //check each field in the record
                        if (s2.ElementAt(i) == sarray[i]) {
                            //if the field value at this index matches the one we're about to put in
                            addit = false;
                        } else {
                            addit = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (indecesToDelimit.Contains(i)) {
                //ensure that delimiters are added to all text field values
                sarray[i] = "'" + sarray[i] + "'";
            }

            if (addit) {
                Queriables.Add(sarray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to break out of your foreach when you detect an `addit == false`.  Otherwise, it will just be set to `true` again on the next loop iteration.

```
{
    addit = false;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Oops, good call, but unfortunately it's still not eliminating duplicate entries after I fixed that.

Comment: You're assuming `addit = true` at the top of your first loop.  Seems that one of your other conditions is torpedoing the duplicate checking.

Comment: YUp.....looks like it's in the duplicate index list.  I just ran a foreach() on it to just toss me a messagebox, and it's filled with duplicates of index 0 for some reason.   Thanks for getting my brain going the right direction again, I'll repost here if resolving the index issue doesn't get things on track.

Comment: Resolved that, but still not getting the duplicates removed.  It seems to flag all records that are duplicates, but puts them all in the list anyway....anyone know why?

Comment: Time to break out the debugger.

Comment: Ready for it?   I very much deserve neg rep for this one.  

Epic fail on my part.   Somehow I managed to enclose all of this in a loop that began toward the top of this particular object.  I was just missing a closing bracket that was alternately closed elsewhere...so any one of my millions of tries probably would have done the job. 

Thanks for the help!